# The Struts dispatcher cannot be found

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I could found an error in my code,kindly help me what mistake i have done below.

**Build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<s:form action="verify">

    <s:textfield name="uname" label="Enter Username"/>
    <s:textfield name="pass" label="Enter the Password"/>

    <s:submit value="Click" align="center" />

</s:form>
```

**Exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: error indicated that you are accessing you jsp directly, try to access them by action

Comment: Even if you are not a newbie and didn't try to access it directly the error comes to you not from the struts2 framework.

Answer (score -1):

Place web.xml file under WEB-INF folder. I was also facing the same problem but placing the web.xml file in correct place resolved the issue.